# How to Create an .ear file using JDeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper

I am new to Jdeveloper. I am using JDeveloper 10g. I have created one project abc.jws under which there are five .jpr folders(DTO.jpr,persistence.jpr,service.jpr,util.jpr,ViewController.jpr). I want to create .ear file for the whole project so that it can be directly put in the production environment. When I right click on the abc.jws and select New, the EAR option under deployment profiles is always disabled. I would highly appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Go to Application -> Deploy and deploy as EAR file. That's it.
In the pop up the location of EAR file generated will be there.

Comment: This was the only one I could follow, but I think it is Application, not Applications. This refers to the word Application a little to the right of File.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. For every project you need a jar so right click on them and select "new"
2. Choose "Deployment Profiles" --> "JAR File"
3. On your main project (in jDev) right click and select new
4. In "General" --> "Deployment Profiles" folder choose "WAR File" (I know you want an EAR file...)
5. Now you should have a deploy descriptor in the "Resources" folder, if it doesn't open automatically then double click on it
6. Give names to the EAR files and WAR files, specify your context-root name and so on
7. In "Profile Dependencies" check the deployment profile of the other projects (so it will recreate the JAR files when ever you make an EAR file)
8. Right click on the deployment descriptor ("file.deploy") and choose "Deploy to EAR file"

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank for your help. 
I followed the steps 1 and 2. But I am confused in step 3.

I have created the .deploy files for all the five projects. As most of the jsp and java files are under ViewController project, i have created abc.deploy under ViewController. I tried to make the war file by Right click on ABC.deploy and select "deploy to WAR file". But it only compiles the project and shows no error. No pop-up window appears. Is there anything wrong in my process? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember no popup should appear, but in the cosole you should see that a file was created and where it is located (or if the process failed). BTW, if you ask to deploy to an EAR file then the WAR should be created automatically.

Comment: yes got it.Thanks a lot.
I have another question.When I import an EAR project,all the jsp,js files are imported. But for java files, only class files are imported.I hv some java files.If I want to make change in a java file,then how to build the new java class after making the changes (is it like Right Click on the project->New->Select JAR under deployment profile?)
Basicaly I need to know how to modify a java file in an existing EAR project(since only class files are there), how to create the new EAR after the change so that new class file is updated.
Would really appreciate your help.Thanks

Comment: Basically you can't modify the `.class` files (you can decompile them but that's not the right way to work). In the deployment descriptor you can choose which files to add to the EAR file. If you'll add the `.java` files then you'd be able to modify them afterwards. Same goes for JAR files.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on your `Application -->Deploy-->FileName.ear` a `.ear` file will be created at specified location

```
C:\JDeveloper\mywork\ADFApplication\deploy\FileName.ear
```